# Querying azure table service gives diffrent results

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I am trying to query azure table storage with Microsoft Azure Storage SDK. Sending simple request returns expected results (similar to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables#retrieve-a-range-of-entities-in-a-partition ). But when I send a more complex query like this one:

```
  (((((((((PartitionKey eq 'LOS-test1-20161218') or (PartitionKey eq 'SPA-test1-20161218')) or (PartitionKey eq 'LOS-test2-20161219')) or (PartitionKey eq 'SPA-test2-20161219')) or (PartitionKey eq 'SPA-test3-20161218')) or (PartitionKey eq 'LOS-test3-20161218')) or (PartitionKey eq 'SPA-test4-20161219')) or (PartitionKey eq 'LOS-test4-20161219')) or (PartitionKey eq 'SPA-test5-20161219')) or (PartitionKey eq 'LOS-test5-20161219')
```

I get only part of expected results (one third). Meanwhile when I run this query with Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer I get correct data.

Why does it happen?

```
private string GenerateFilterCondition(string s, string c, DateTime date)
{
        return TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition(
            "PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal,
            s + "-" + c + "-" + date.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
}

private List<SiteSpecificDataTableDataSet> GetSiteSpecificDataTableDataSet()
{           
    _connection.Open();
    DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

    TableQuery<DataEntity> tq = new TableQuery<DataEntity>().Where(GenerateFilterCondition("SPA", "test5", selectedDate));
    tq = AddFilterORToTableQuery(tq.FilterString, GenerateFilterCondition("LOS", "test5", selectedDate));
    tq = AddFilterORToTableQuery(tq.FilterString, GenerateFilterCondition("SPA", "test4", selectedDate.AddDays(1)));
    tq = AddFilterORToTableQuery(tq.FilterString, GenerateFilterCondition("LOS", "test4", selectedDate.AddDays(1)));
    tq = AddFilterORToTableQuery(tq.FilterString, GenerateFilterCondition("LOS", "test3", selectedDate));
    tq = AddFilterORToTableQuery(tq.FilterString, GenerateFilterCondition("SPA", "test3", selectedDate));
    tq = AddFilterORToTableQuery(tq.FilterString, GenerateFilterCondition("LOS", "test2", selectedDate.AddDays(1)));
    tq = AddFilterORToTableQuery(tq.FilterString, GenerateFilterCondition("SPA", "test2", selectedDate.AddDays(1)));
    tq = AddFilterORToTableQuery(tq.FilterString, GenerateFilterCondition("LOS", "test1", selectedDate.AddDays(1)));
    tq = AddFilterORToTableQuery(tq.FilterString, GenerateFilterCondition("SPA", "test1", selectedDate.AddDays(1)));

    IEnumerable<DataEntity> entities = _connection.QueryData(tq);
}
```

And `QueryData` looks like:

```
    IEnumerable<DataEntity> res;
            List<DataEntity> queryResult = new List<DataEntity>();
            CloudTableClient tableClient = _storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
            CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("data");
            TableContinuationToken tct = null;
            do
            {
                // Retrieve a segment (up to 1,000 entities).
                TableQuerySegment<DataEntity> tableQueryResult = table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, tct).Result;                
                if (tableQueryResult.Results.Count == 0) break;
                tct = tableQueryResult.ContinuationToken;
                foreach (var result in tableQueryResult.Results)
                {
                    queryResult.Add(result);
                }

            } while (tct != null);
            res = queryResult;
```

Comment: How are you running it, show some code?

Comment: The query you have written in the 1st code block is not the same as the one you're generating via code. Can you please check that the same query is used in both places?

Comment: Yes i am sure that they are correct, i copied value from debugger. Later i was playing with code, so dates may be a little diffrent. They are OK.

Comment: “if (tableQueryResult.Results.Count == 0) break” this condition is incorrect, you may still need to continue querying even when the result is empty. The correct condition should be: "if (tableQueryResult.ContinuationToken == null) break"

Comment: BTW, querying different Partition Keys in one filter string is highly not recommended since per Azure Table design it'll result in whole table scan which is terrible in performance. You need to split your query into multiple (one Partition Key at a time) queries to achieve better performance.

Comment: Thanks @ZhaoxingLu-Microsoft You were right. Now it run good.

Comment: My pleasure. Could you please mark my answer as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This condition in your code is incorrect: "if (tableQueryResult.Results.Count == 0) break", you may still need to continue querying even when the result is empty.

The correct condition should be: "if (tableQueryResult.ContinuationToken == null) break".

BTW, querying different Partition Keys in one filter string is highly not recommended since per Azure Table design it'll result in whole table scan which is terrible in performance. You need to split your query into multiple (one Partition Key at a time) queries to achieve better performance.